# simba-package R: Comparing mean similarity between subsets of data with missing values

Tags: r, missing-data

I am trying to compare mean similarity between 3 subsets of data using the com.sim function (simba-package), but I’m having trouble getting the function to ignore missing values and correctly run the analysis.

Some background on my data and what I’ve done so far: My data is binary, but unlike the kinds of data for which the function is written, I working with skeletal remains, which are typically incomplete and fragmented. Thus, ~10% of my data matrix has missing values.

When I run this command in R

> com.sim(mydata, subs, simil = "jaccard", binary = TRUE, permutations = 1000, alpha = 0.05, bonfc = TRUE)

I get the following error message:

> Error in diffmean(as.numeric(sim(veg[subs == (comb[x, 1]), ], method = simil)),  : 
>     There are NA values. Consider setting na.rm accordingly

I subsequently modified the code of the function to the following (modification in bold):

> if (binary) {
>           tmp <- lapply(c(1:nrow(comb)), function(x) diffmean(as.numeric(sim(veg[subs == 
>               (comb[x, 1]), ], method = simil,)), as.numeric(sim(veg[subs == 
>               (comb[x, 2]), ], method = simil, )), **na.rm = TRUE**))

Now, the function runs, but it is excluding all cases with at least 1 missing value (which is nearly half the data set!!). It seems that it is deleting cases w/ NA listwise, whereas I’d prefer pairwise deletion so that similarity coefficients can still be calculated between cases with missing values (but just excluding the variables with NA from the calculation).  Is there any way to accomplish this within com.sim?  I know other functions such as simil (proxy-package) can handle missing values when calculating a matrix of Jaccard coefficients, but it seems that the sim functions in simba weren’t built this way.

I’m have zero coding experience (is it obvious?) and so I would appreciate any help or advice on options to pursue!

Thank you very much, and please let me know if I can provide additional information.
Best,
Matt

Comment: Would changing this part of code to `lapply(c(1:nrow(comb)), function(x) diffmean(na.omit(as.numeric(1 - dist(veg[subs == (comb[x, 1]), ], method = "binary"))), na.omit(as.numeric(1 - dist(veg[subs == (comb[x, 2]), ], method = "binary")))))` work? `sim` generates `NA`s so I used `1 - dist(., method = "binary")` instead of `sim(., method = "jaccard")` which (at least on the testings I did) provides the same results. `dist` excludes `NA`s. `na.omit` ignores `NA`s in each compared pair. Hope you'll make something out of this.

Comment: Thank you @alexis_laz, that did the trick!  I appreciate you help.  I'm starting to get the logic of R . . .